# How to change the spring-boot-feign address during runtime

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I'm using the following interface definition in my application:

```
@FeignClient(name = "inventory-manage", 
             configuration = EtermTestRequestShoppingConfiguration.class,
             url="http://xxxx")
public interface EtermTestRequestShopping {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                    value = "/inventory/manager/shopping")
  @ResponseBody
  Single<String> shoping(@RequestBody ShoppingSearchReq shoppingSearchReq);
}
```

How can I change the url value during the runtime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the feign URL during the runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733569/how-can-i-change-the-feign-url-during-the-runtime)