# How can I change the feign URL during the runtime?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

`@FeignClient(name = "test", url="http://xxxx")`

How can I change the feign URL (url="http://xxxx") during the runtime? because the URL can only be determined at run time.

Answer (score 75):

You can add an unannotated URI parameter (that can potentially be determined at runtime) and that will be the base path that will be used for the request. E.g.:

```java
    @FeignClient(name = "dummy-name", url = "https://this-is-a-placeholder.com")
    public interface MyClient {
        @PostMapping(path = "/create")
        UserDto createUser(URI baseUrl, @RequestBody UserDto userDto);
    }
```

And then the usage will be:

```java
    @Autowired 
    private MyClient myClient;
    ...
    URI determinedBasePathUri = URI.create("https://my-determined-host.com");
    myClient.createUser(determinedBasePathUri, userDto);
```

This will send a `POST` request to `https://my-determined-host.com/create` ([source](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/318#issuecomment-190070800)).

Comment: can `path` (in your example, it is `/create`) also be dynamic?

Comment: @lily Yes. You should use `@PathVarable`. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803731/spring-mvc-pathvariable)

Answer (score 32):

Feign has a way to provide the dynamic URLs and endpoints at runtime.

The following steps have to be followed:

1. In the `FeignClient` interface we have to remove the URL parameter. We have to use `@RequestLine` annotation to mention the REST method (GET, PUT, POST, etc.):

```java
    @FeignClient(name="customerProfileAdapter")
    public interface CustomerProfileAdaptor {

        // @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/get_all")
        @RequestLine("GET")
        public List<Customer> getAllCustomers(URI baseUri); 
     
        // @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/add")
        @RequestLine("POST")
        public ResponseEntity<CustomerProfileResponse> addCustomer(URI baseUri, Customer customer);
     
        @RequestLine("DELETE")
        public ResponseEntity<CustomerProfileResponse> deleteCustomer(URI baseUri, String mobile);
    }
```

2. In RestController you have to import FeignClientConfiguration
3. You have to write one RestController constructor with encoder and decoder as parameters.
4. You need to build the `FeignClient` with the encoder, decoder.
5. While calling the `FeignClient` methods, provide the URI (BaserUrl + endpoint) along with rest call parameters if any.

```java
    @RestController
    @Import(FeignClientsConfiguration.class)
    public class FeignDemoController {
    
        CustomerProfileAdaptor customerProfileAdaptor;
    
        @Autowired
        public FeignDemoController(Decoder decoder, Encoder encoder) {
            customerProfileAdaptor = Feign.builder().encoder(encoder).decoder(decoder) 
               .target(Target.EmptyTarget.create(CustomerProfileAdaptor.class));
        }
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/get_all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() throws URISyntaxException {
            return customerProfileAdaptor
                .getAllCustomers(new URI("http://localhost:8090/customer-profile/get_all"));
        }
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<CustomerProfileResponse> addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) 
                throws URISyntaxException {
            return customerProfileAdaptor
                .addCustomer(new URI("http://localhost:8090/customer-profile/add"), customer);
        }
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<CustomerProfileResponse> deleteCustomer(@RequestBody String mobile)
                throws URISyntaxException {
            return customerProfileAdaptor
                .deleteCustomer(new URI("http://localhost:8090/customer-profile/delete"), mobile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But can I read the url from properties/yaml file, injecting with `@Value` or `@ConfigurationProperties`? I cannot find how to do it.

Comment: This approaches changes the signature of the methods and is therefor not a good solution. See the answer of @Forest10 below for a better solution using Spring.

Answer (score 9):

use feign.Target.EmptyTarget

```
@Bean
public BotRemoteClient botRemoteClient(){
    return Feign.builder().target(Target.EmptyTarget.create(BotRemoteClient.class));
}

public interface BotRemoteClient {

    @RequestLine("POST /message")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    BotMessageRs sendMessage(URI url, BotMessageRq message);
}

botRemoteClient.sendMessage(new URI("http://google.com"), rq)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create the client manually:

```
@Import(FeignClientsConfiguration.class)
class FooController {

    private FooClient fooClient;

    private FooClient adminClient;

    @Autowired
    public FooController(ResponseEntityDecoder decoder, SpringEncoder encoder, Client client) {
        this.fooClient = Feign.builder().client(client)
            .encoder(encoder)
            .decoder(decoder)
            .requestInterceptor(new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("user", "user"))
            .target(FooClient.class, "http://PROD-SVC");
        this.adminClient = Feign.builder().client(client)
            .encoder(encoder)
            .decoder(decoder)
            .requestInterceptor(new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("admin", "admin"))
            .target(FooClient.class, "http://PROD-SVC");
     }
}
```

From documentation: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#_creating_feign_clients_manually

Answer (score 4):

In interface you can change url by Spring annotations. The base URI is configured in yml Spring configuration.

```
   @FeignClient(
            name = "some.client",
            url = "${some.serviceUrl:}",
            configuration = FeignClientConfiguration.class
    )

public interface SomeClient {

    @GetMapping("/metadata/search")
    String search(@RequestBody SearchCriteria criteria);

    @GetMapping("/files/{id}")
    StreamingResponseBody downloadFileById(@PathVariable("id") UUID id);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use Interceptor: RequestInterceptor

feign will replace the target url if you set target host in interceptor:

```java
  // source code of feign
  Request targetRequest(RequestTemplate template) {
    for (RequestInterceptor interceptor : requestInterceptors) {
      interceptor.apply(template);
    }
    return target.apply(template);
  }

  public Request apply(RequestTemplate input) {
    if (input.url().indexOf("http") != 0) {
      input.target(url());
    }
    return input.request();
  }
```

Custom you interceptor:

```java
public class DynamicFeignUrlInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        if (isNotDynamicPath(template)) {
            return;
        }
        template.target(getHost());
    }

    private boolean isNotDynamicPath(RequestTemplate template) {
        // TODO Determine whether it is dynamic according to your logic
        return false;
    }

    private String getHost() {
        // use any host you want, host must be contained key word of 'http' 
        return "http://example.com";
    }

}
```

The advantage of this is that if there is already a large amount of feign client code, it can be implemented without modifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

***Use @PathVariable like this:***

```
@Service    
@FeignClient(name = "otherservicename", decode404 = true)    
public interface myService {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/basepath/{request-path}")
ResponseEntity<String> getResult(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token,
                                                      @RequestBody HashMap<String, String> reqBody,
                                                      @PathVariable(value = "request-path") String requestPath);
}
```

Then from service, construct the dynamic url path and send the request:

```
String requestPath = "approve-req";

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = myService.getResult(
                token, reqBody, requestPath);
```

***Your request url will be at: "/basepath/approve-req"***

Comment: The author is asking about dynamic URL, not about dynamic request path. Your answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score -2):

I prefer to build feign client by configuration to pass a url at run time (in my case i get the url by service name from consul discovery service)

so i extend feign target class as below:

```
public class DynamicTarget<T> implements Target<T> {
private final CustomLoadBalancer loadBalancer;
private final String serviceId;
private final Class<T> type;

public DynamicTarget(String serviceId, Class<T> type, CustomLoadBalancer loadBalancer) {
    this.loadBalancer = loadBalancer;
    this.serviceId = serviceId;
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
public Class<T> type() {
    return type;
}

@Override
public String name() {
    return serviceId;
}

@Override
public String url() {
    return loadBalancer.getServiceUrl(name());
}

@Override
public Request apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
    requestTemplate.target(url());
    return requestTemplate.request();
}
}


 var target = new DynamicTarget<>(Services.service_id, ExamsAdapter.class, loadBalancer);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
                package commxx;

                import java.net.URI;
                import java.net.URISyntaxException;

                import feign.Client;
                import feign.Feign;
                import feign.RequestLine;
                import feign.Retryer;
                import feign.Target;
                import feign.codec.Encoder;
                import feign.codec.Encoder.Default;
                import feign.codec.StringDecoder;

                public class FeignTest {

                    public interface someItfs {

                 
                        @RequestLine("GET")
                        String getx(URI baseUri);
                    }

                    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
                        String url = "http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=ddd";  //ok..
                        someItfs someItfs1 = Feign.builder()
                                // .logger(new FeignInfoLogger()) // 自定义日志类，继承 feign.Logger
                                // .logLevel(Logger.Level.BASIC)// 日志级别
                                // Default(long period, long maxPeriod, int maxAttempts)
                                .client(new Client.Default(null, null))// 默认 http
                                .retryer(new Retryer.Default(5000, 5000, 1))// 5s超时，仅1次重试
                            //  .encoder(Encoder)
                            //  .decoder(new StringDecoder())
                                .target(Target.EmptyTarget.create(someItfs.class));

                //       String url = "http://localhost:9104/";
                //         
                        System.out.println(someItfs1.getx(new URI(url)));
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Could you put some context around your answer. Also please clean-up the code, removing references to Baidu and non-relevant commented out code.