# How to create feign clients with different urls for the same interface

Tags: spring-boot, rest-client, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I had a Feign Client created with SpringFramework openFeign, but wanted to hit the same rest end points with a different environment url. As I set the url at the annotation, wanted to check if there is some other way to do this.

**Feign Client through Spring Framework Open Feign**

```
@FeignClient(
        value = "adminClient",
        url = "${api.url}",
        configuration = {AuthConfig.class}
)
public interface AdminClient {

    @PostMapping("/api/testDomains/{domainName}/resources")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    Resource addResource(
            @RequestParam("domainName") String domainName,
            Resource resource);
}
```

**Application properties yaml file**

```
domain:
        url: https://test.com
        url2: https://test2.com
```

**AuthConfig class**

```
@Bean("authenticatedHttpClient")
    public HttpClient httpClientBuilder(@Value("${authenticator.type}") String authTYpe, @Value("${authenticator.key-tab.feign-path:#{null}}") String keytabPath, @Value("${authenticator.key-tab.principal:#{null}}") String keytabPrincipal) {

        if (authTYpe.equalsIgnoreCase("current-user")) {
            return SafeguardClients.forCurrentUser(true)
                    .create(HttpClientBuilder.class)
                    .withGsssoToken()
                    .build();
        } else {
            return SafeguardClients.forKeyTab(keytabPath, new KerberosPrincipal(keytabPrincipal))
                    .create(HttpClientBuilder.class)
                    .withGsssoToken()
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Client client(@Qualifier("authenticatedHttpClient") final HttpClient clientBuilder) {
        return new ApacheHttpClient(clientBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: may be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733569/how-can-i-change-the-feign-url-during-the-runtime